# Is there a way to bypass .zshrc on login?

Tags: zsh

I'm enjoying learning ZSH, but one thing's bugging me. If I put something in my .zshrc that renders the shell useless (I'm playing with something that affects the way the keyboard is interpreted), then I could end up not being able to fix it unless I can bypass my zshrc on login.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to `bash`, `zsh` doesn't read `.zshrc` when running commands over `ssh`. So if you mess up your `zshrc`, you can always do:

```
ssh machine mv .zshrc .zshrc.disabled
```

from another machine to put your `.zshrc` out of the way.

If you want to test a zshrc, you can put it in another directory and run `zsh` as:

```
ZDOTDIR=/that/dir zsh
```

to run zsh with that `.zshrc` (or `.zshenv` or `.zprofile`/`.zlogin`/`.zlogout` with `zsh -l`).

You can also login with that ZDOTDIR over ssh with:

```
ssh -t machine ZDOTDIR=/that/dir zsh -l
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first statement be due to using `bash` as your login shell on the remote machine, as opposed to any inherent difference between `bash` and `zsh`?

Comment: @chepner, I'm saying that would your login shell on the remote machine be `bash`, you'd be screwed as `bash` reads `~/.bashrc` when invoked over `ssh`. With `zsh` (as login shell on the remote machine), you don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an alternative config file and invoke the shell with that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727172/how-to-load-different-zshrc-file-via-commandline-option .

Comment: Yeah, but that's for starting zsh from another shell. You can't do that over SSH, right? As in `ssh foo@example.com --alternative-zshrc=whatnot`

Comment: You can execute commands given as arguments to `ssh` : `ssh user@host zsh --rcs /home/user/zsh.alt`

Comment: @schaiba, `--rcs` only enables the rcs option (so reads the .zshrc...) and then that interprets the zsh.alt as a script, so it's not what we want here.